# Gulp - Improve performance of gulp.watch on bundled js files

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

I am having issues with the performance of browser livereloading whenever I make a change to a `js` file. In my gulp setup, I have the following watches:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(config.paths.html, ['html']);
    gulp.watch(config.paths.js, ['js', 'lint']);
    gulp.watch(config.paths.css, ['css']);
});
```

Thus, whenever there's a change to a `js` file, the `js` and `lint` tasks are triggered. They are as follows:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    browserify(config.paths.mainJs)
        .transform(reactify)
        .bundle()
        .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dest + '/scripts'))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.paths.js)
        .pipe(lint({config: 'eslint.config.json'}))
        .pipe(lint.format());
});
```

With this setup, livereloading on `js` file changes doesn't scale. As the project gets bigger, the live reloads take longer. Even a small project with about a dozen JS files already takes 3.8 seconds per reload.

I know the problem is that on every `js` file change, you're reactifying and bundling every `js` file in the project, which is an expensive operation and completely redundant for all the `js` files other than the one you changed. What's a better way to handle the live reloading? I know webpack uses hot module reloading, is there a `gulp` equivalent for this?